# Calling component method from it's mounted method

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have this component and in the mounted function I defined an event which is firing correctly.

That event calls a method defined inside methods: but it complains saying

> methodTest is not a function

```
  Vue.component('collection', {
    props: ['items'],
    template: '<p>test</p>',
    methods: {
      methodTest: function(param) {
        console.log("param: " + param);
      }
    },
    mounted: function() {
      $('#element').bind('eventFiring', function(e, param) {
        console.log("--------------");
        console.log(e);
        console.log(param);
    // These console logs are being printed
        console.log("--------------");
    // calling methodTest and crashing
        this.methodTest(param);
      });
    }
  });

  new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      items: [],
    }
  });
```

Isnt it the way to do it?

**Update:**

This solves the issue [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

BUT, its very tricky to make the correct question so the search engine routes you to that link....

Comment: `this` inside the anonymous function you're passing is not the component.

Comment: ahhh damned js, I see, var component = this; then just call it inside...